# notarize macOS application on electron fail because- not signed- what should i sign?

Tags: macos, electron, certificate, notarize, electron-notarize

i am new in the macOS development its been difficult to me to understand how to notarize my electron js application in apple servers, i successfully made a script that send my build to apple servers but the application cant been notarized, i get this message in the logs:
"Package build.zip has no signed executables or bundles. No tickets can be generated."
i don't know that should i sign, because the "build" is a folder.
can you help me to find the problem and tell me how to fix it? i have developer ID certificate but i don't know what to sign, or maybe the file I am sending to apple is not the file that i should send (i send the build folder)

thank you!

Comment: Are you going to publish it to the mac app store? or just generating the signed app for distribution?

Comment: You must notarize an `.app` bundle, not the build folder.